# C++ modern string pointers

Tags: c++, string, c++11, pointers

is it recommended to use pointer on an modern c++ string?
Like this:

```
std::string *test = new string();
anyfunction(test);
```

In the **test** variable is a very long text. So i thought, that it easier and faster to act with an pointer.

Is this a good or a bad code?

Comment: c++ prefer references. For instance `std::string test; void anyfunction(const std::string& s); anyfunction(test)`.

Comment: ***is it recommended to use pointer on an modern c++ string?*** No don't do that ever. In the last million lines of `c++` code I have written  I have not done that a single time.

Answer (score 3):

In general this is a **really bad** idea − for two reasons:

Secondary reason: You are using manual heap allocation without wrapping it in a smart pointer. But adding e.g. `std::unique_ptr` would just be putting a band-aid on the symptons.

Primary reason: You are thinking in the right direction (avoid unnecessary copies of large junks of data), but you’re using the wrong tool. The type of the function’s parameter is the right tool.

Does the function only need to read the string? Then its signature should be:

```
return_type anyfunction(const std::string& test);
```

Passing by const ref will not copy the string. If you need write-access as well, leave out the `const`:

```
return_type anyfunction(std::string& test);
```

Again, no copy is made. Moving the string into the function might also be an option. But it’s hard to say without further context.

Answer (score 1):

An std::string is basically created on the heap. Some optimising version will create short strings on the stack for speed, but that's not an issue here.

Creating with new is not recommended because the object can't auto-destroy as it goes out of scope. (Sometimes you want this behaviour, but that's rare, really you should regard new as obsolete for beginning C++ programmers). And it won't substantially affect your stack use, since only a few trivial control variables go on the stack.

You haven't shown how you initialise it. Or how you intend to use the data. Whilst passing a const std::string & is really just alternative notation for passing a pointer, it's more idiomatic. However modern C++ is moving to string views. Essentially you create the string, then you create views onto the data. If the string is very long, this could be important. For example, to do searches for short substrings on a long string is very time consuming if your long string is fat array, pretty fast if it is a suffix tree.

String views are still experimental:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view

Answer (score 1):

Using pointers means another level of indirection. C++11 has move semantics means one can easily move the copy of the string without doing a deep copy which mostly removes the need to `new` a string or any other C++ object.

Answer (score -1):

it is not recommended in the modern C++ to use the raw pointer.Instead, you can use smart pointers. There are four smart pointers in C++11- std::auto_ptr, std::unique_ptr,
std::shared_ptr, and std::weak_ptr.
All are designed to help manage the lifetimes of dynamically allocated objects, i.e., to avoid resource leaks by ensuring that such objects are destroyed in the appropriate manner at the appropriate time (including
in the event of exceptions).

Comment: auto_ptr has been deprecated. And in this case the best advice is not to use pointers at all.

Comment: Please, note that [std::auto_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) is deprecated since C++11 and not present in C++17

Comment: What can i use instead of std::auto_ptr? Because i heard it is deprecated.

Comment: yes, i do agree. auto_ptr has deprecated.
@ Hball :
std::unique_ptr does everything std::auto_ptr does, plus more. It does it as efficiently,
and it does it without warping what it means to copy an object. It’s better
than std::auto_ptr in every way